# Zurb Ink Panel Stretches across page

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, html-email, zurb-ink

I am using Zurb Ink to make html emails. With the panel, it looks correct in the browser with it being 601px wide. But on outlook on Safari OS(Mac book)the panel goes all the way to across the email(like a footer or header).

Should it be like this on outlook in Safari? Or is there something wrong with my code?

```
           <table class="row">
                <tr>
                    <td class="panel" style="background: #ECF8FF; border-color: #b9e5ff">

                        <table class="twelve columns container">
                            {% for item in object_list %}
                            <tr>
                                 <td class="four sub-columns">
                                     {% if not item.user_assigned %}
                                     <table class="tiny-button small radius alert">
                                         <tr>
                                             <td>unssigned</td>
                                     {% else %}
                                     <table class="tiny-button small radius success">
                                         <tr>
                                             <td>assigned</td>
                                    {% endif %}
                                         </tr>
                                     </table>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="eight sub-columns last">
                                     {{ item.date_due }} - {{ item.action }}
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="expander"></td>
                             </tr>
                             {% endfor %}
                         </table>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is because you are missing wrapper and container.

In the [docs](http://zurb.com/ink/docs.php) it mentions the following:

**container** - Constrains the content to a 580px wrapper on large screens (95% on small screens) and centers it within the body.

**wrapper** - Wraps each .columns table, in order to create a gutter between columns and force them to expand to full width on small screens.

Comment: Adding an <a> tag to the buttons might be a good idea as well. ;)